# Merge these 2 MySQL query into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distance

I explain you the problem. I have two tables : "listing" who contain all my lists with different informations and particulary one : a city ID. I have a second table "city" who contain the complete list of all cities of my countries with many informations : latitude, longitude, city name, etc.

I want to show all listing ordered by distance between actual point (geolocalised, I have lat/lng) and cities in the listing table.

Actualy, I do this with 2 MySQL queries, and it's work :

```
$formula = "(6366*acos(cos(radians($latitude))*cos(radians(`latitude`))*cos(radians(`longitude`) -radians($longitude))+sin(radians($latitude))*sin(radians(`latitude`))))";

        $q = "SELECT *,$formula AS dist FROM ".$this->db_city." WHERE $formula<='$distance' ORDER by dist ASC";
        $q = $this->db->query($q);
$resultSQL = $q->result_array();
```

And this one :

```
if ($localization != ''){
            if ($whereClause == ''){
                //$whereClause .= ' WHERE address_city LIKE "'.$localization.'"';
                $loc = '';
                foreach ($localization as $key => $value) {
                    if ($loc == ''){
                        $loc .= '"'.$value.'"';
                    }else{
                        $loc .= ', "'.$value.'"';
                    }
                }
                $whereClause .= ' WHERE address_city IN ('.$loc.')';
            }else{
                //$whereClause .= ' && address_city LIKE "'.$localization.'"';
                $loc = '';
                foreach ($localization as $key => $value) {
                    if ($loc == ''){
                        $loc .= '"'.$value.'"';
                    }else{
                        $loc .= ', "'.$value.'"';
                    }
                }
                $whereClause .= ' && address_city IN ('.$loc.')';
            }
        }

        $q = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->db_listing.$whereClause." ORDER BY created_stamp DESC";
```

It's work, but the problem is I don't have the "dist" parameter accessible in this second query, so I can't order by dist. The solution for that is to merge the first big query (the one with the formula) with the second.

I tried with LEFT JOIN, but it didn't work. Can you help me please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will going to return you all the cities those with in the radius of $distance from provided longitude and latitudes.

```
"SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($longitude- 
    `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS distance FROM location WHERE (((acos(sin(($latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($longitude- 
    `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) <= $distance"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm thanks but it just do the same thing that the first query. It's working but I want to have this "dist" value available in the second query. The one who get my listing.

Comment: @jackson: seems you forget to place name of the table in your second query, $this->db_listing.$whereClause started with where clause omits name of the table, can you place name of the table?

share you data structure I will help you.

Comment: Table "listing"
id, listing_name, city
Table "city"
id, lat, lng, city_name

So globally I would like to do :

SELECT * FROM listing ORDER BY dist
But, the "dist" field is generated by the first query, not the second.